# How to issue a push notification with GCM and Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to figure out how I can issue a push notification using Google Cloud Messaging to my Android App.

I have a MySQL database on Google Cloud SQL, with a Cloud Endpoints API that I use to interact with that MySQL database (Inserts, Updates, etc.).

Now, I want to make a table called "messages' in my MySQL database and whenever there is a new message is inserted there, I want my Android App to be notified of this via GCM.

I know I need to have a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the push notification coming in, but I am not sure where exactly I should execute the code to send the push notification with GCM (in my Cloud Endpoints?) nor do I know how GCM would know that my messages table has been updated with a new row.

Could someone help me understand this intermediate step or point me in the right direction to some tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a quick fix on this, it won't happen because this is a non-trivial problem. The initial signaling itself is easy enough depending on the framework being used. For example, in django I use signals so that when a model is saved to DB, the post-save signal can send the GCM message.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to add a task to a push queue when you write the message record to the DB. The task can find all required recipients for that message when it runs, and send the GCM message to each recipient.

This allows you to rate throttle messaging and offload some of the work from the request.

---

Edit for clarity:

1. Cloud endpoint handler writes to your DB within a transaction
2. Cloud endpoint handler puts a task on a task queue (a push queue) within
   the same transaction
3. Cloud endpoint returns
4. Push queue task is executed on another handler asynchronously
5. Task handler finds message recipients (DB query or similar)
6. Task handler sends GCM message to each recipient using the payload from the DB

The advantages of this are:

- That the message save and task creation are transactional, if either fails you can retry or send an error back to the client
- The cloud endpoints invocation does not need to wait for the GCM RPCs to complete (i.e. its quicker)
- If GCM task processing fails for whatever reason, it will retry based on the push queue rules
- You can independently control the rate of GCM messaging using queue configuration
- You can offload GCM messaging and related processing to different module or backend and have a different consumption profile to your REST front ends.

Comment: So I would have my Cloud Endpoints method write to the DB, then also send a push notification to whatever device the message was for?